# How can I add a list of Elements to a Word Document?

Tags: java, ms-word, element

```
Elements links = getLinkList();

for (Element link : links) {
    System.out.println(link.attr("href"));
}
```

I have a link of Elements that I've extracted from a web page using JSoup. I now want to write each link in a Word document line by line. How can I do this?

**Update:** As demonstrated by Mike below...

```
private static void createSimpleDocument(Elements links) throws Exception {
    XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument();
    XWPFParagraph tmpParagraph = document.createParagraph();

    for (Element link : links) {
        XWPFRun tmpRun = tmpParagraph.createRun();
        String linkText = link.attr("href");
        tmpRun.setText(linkText);
        tmpRun.addBreak();
        tmpRun.addBreak();
    }

    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("...");
    document.write(out);
    out.close();
}
```

I'm able to successfully save and read the document, but for POI processing purposes, I need to save it as an OLE2 Office document. Otherwise I get this error:

```
The supplied data appears to be in the Office 2007+ XML. POI only supports OLE2 Office documents
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Apache POI https://poi.apache.org/

```
Elements links = getLinkList();
XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument();   
XWPFParagraph tmpParagraph = document.createParagraph();  
for (Element link : links) {
  XWPFRun tmpRun = tmpParagraph.createRun();   
  tmpRun.setText(link.attr("href"));   
}
```